# Ошибка: "Не удается выполнить привязки исполняющей среды по нулевой ссылке"

Tags: c#, json, парсер, vkontakte-api

Появляется ошибка при попытке вывести фотографии групп пользователя.
Вот код метода:

```
void Save_Photo()
    {
        string photo = "";
        string response = FunctionGroupPolz.Otpravka_Zaprosa_Polichit_Spisok_Group(user_id, 0, 10, access_token);
        dynamic json = JObject.Parse(response);

        try
        {
           photo = json.response[1].photo_200;
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
               photo = json.response[1].photo_100;
            }
            catch
            {
                photo = json.response[1].photo_50;
            }
        }
        LG_Log_Text.Text = photo; 
    }
```

Код метода для получения списка групп:

```
        public static string Otpravka_Zaprosa_Polichit_Spisok_Group(string Id, int offset, int count, string token)
    {
        var dannie = new HttpRequest();
        string response = dannie.Get("https://api.vk.com/method/"
            + "groups.get" + "?"
            + "&" + "user_id=" + Id
            + "&" + "extended=" + "1"
            + "&" + "offset=" + offset
            + "&" + "count=" + count
            + "&" + "v=" + "5.126" 
            + "&" + "access_token=" + token).ToString();
        return response;
    }
```

Вот результат json запроса:

```
{"response":{"count":502,"items":[{"id":32176202,"name":"Alt-Right","screen_name":"alterright","is_closed":0,"type":"page","is_admin":0,"is_member":1,"is_advertiser":0,"photo_50":"https:\/\/sun1-85.userapi.com\/impg\/c857628\/v857628503\/18d7a8\/tBj0PmnAYfk.jpg?size=50x0&quality=96&crop=0,0,1923,1923&sign=84e6d295514ffe2355b83b14a81a129e&c_uniq_tag=xacfiexJ2FVinkwLGFjH0FFP3ZPnKwompasvkDDB01c&ava=1","photo_100":"https:\/\/sun1-85.userapi.com\/impg\/c857628\/v857628503\/18d7a8\/tBj0PmnAYfk.jpg?size=100x0&quality=96&crop=0,0,1923,1923&sign=cd2b9d322ff5bfb1fcfcea52e5447512&c_uniq_tag=dSkQxi4CRtpviH77wdG3sqU22eVd2hARoXM7gRDc2n8&ava=1","photo_200":"https:\/\/sun1-85.userapi.com\/impg\/c857628\/v857628503\/18d7a8\/tBj0PmnAYfk.jpg?size=200x0&quality=96&crop=0,0,1923,1923&sign=65c7024905cee1457e5fae7b52f74b6b&c_uniq_tag=cuB-WG6aQWmOIpg1IQIfE0g85kqu9PSiVA3VVR7Waj8&ava=1"}]}}
```

Comment: Текст ошибки через гугл транслейт переводили, или он на самом деле такой? Вопрос непонятен. В какой строке ошибка? Что это за код, как он работает, и как он должен работать?

Comment: 1. Текст ошибки такой на самом деле
2. Ошибка происходит в методе Save_photo в блоке try catch
3. Программа должна извлекать из ответа на запрос ссылку на фотографию аватарки группы, в зависимости от того какая есть (большая, средняя или маленькая)

Comment: А у вас есть уверенность, что `json.responce[1]` не равен null? Нумерация же обычно идёт с нулевого элемента.

Comment: Первым элементом идёт count

Comment: покажите полный текст json ответа, приватную информацию можно скрыть. Добавьте этот ответ в ваш вопрос, его можно редактировать.

Comment: json.respon**c**e - опечатка? Нужно respon**s**e?

Comment: добавил json ответ

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , после того как исправил опечатку выводит ошибку в том же блоке кода: "Accessed JObject values with invalid key value: 1. Object property name expected."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Меня в такое уныние ввергают подобные вопросы :(. Их огромное множество на stackoverflow.
Авторы этих вопросов наугад лепят обращение к свойствам json-объектов и элементам json-массивов.

Для начала зайдите на [json.org](https://www.json.org) и изучите структуру формата JSON. Там делов на несколько минут.
Кратко: json состоит из *объектов*, заключённых в фигурные скобки `{ }` и *массивов*, заключённых в квадратные скобки `[ ]`.

Я отформатировал ваш json для удобства просмотра:

```
{
  "response": {
    "count": 502,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 32176202,
        "name": "Alt-Right",
        "screen_name": "alterright",
        "is_closed": 0,
        "type": "page",
        "is_admin": 0,
        "is_member": 1,
        "is_advertiser": 0,
        "photo_50": "https:...",
        "photo_100": "https:...",
        "photo_200": "https:..."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

У корневого объекта одно свойство `response`. Которое тоже является *объектом* - фигурные скобки. С какой стати вы пишете `responce[1]`? (Кстати, опечатку вы так и не исправили). Ещё раз: `response` - это объект, а не массив.

А вот `items` - массив. К нему следует обращаться `items[i]`, где `i` - индекс.

Итого, если вам нужно обратиться к свойствам `photo_*`, это может выглядеть так:

```
string photo = json.response.items[0].photo_50;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо